# How to make a label to take entire Frame element space

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grid with Frame elements as cells. Within some frame elements, there's label elements. The problem is the label stretches only as much as its content.

My goal is to make labels take the entire space of its parent elements(Frames).
I tried setting the VerticalOptions and HorizontalOptions properties to "StartAndExpand" and also "FillAndExpand" to no avail

```
<Grid>
    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Text="Hello" />
    </Frame>
 ...
</Grid>
```

Thank you!

EDIT: To clarify, I want to stretch label itself but not its text.

Comment: do you want the text itself to scale up to fit its container?

Comment: To clarify Jason's question: If you set a `BackgroundColor` on `Label`, you'll see that the `Label` *is* occupying the whole frame. Unfortunately Xamarin Forms doesn't have a mechanism to "automatically scale" *text*, so the *letters* `H` `e` `l` `l` `o` don't get bigger. You have to set `FontSize` to some number, to get bigger text. AFAIK, the only way to *automatically* do this, involves writing custom c# code. google `xamarin forms automatically scale text to fit` to find what different people have done. Unfortunately, solving this really is as complicated as those answers show...

Comment: ... maybe that google search will find a plug-in that makes it easier. I don't see any "official" xamarin or xamarin community plug-in, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Set Frame padding=0?

Comment: Thanks for replies guys! Setting of frame padding to 0 and horizontal and vertical options to FillAndExpand solved it.
@Shaw if you make it an answer, I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Frame` has a default `padding`, simply set it manually like below.

```
<Frame padding="0">
    <....>
</Frame>
```

Plus, sometimes label with long text not behave correctly inside the `Frame`,
and one workaround is to wrap the Label with a `StackLayout`.